# Сумма квадратов

Tags: c++, математика

Нужно найти сумму квадратов четных чисел от 1 до N(введено с клавиатуры), числа должны быть больше 0, иначе выйдет ошибка.
У меня в коде выводится только квадрат последнего введенного числа.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int a;
    int N;
    int total=0;
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Введите кол-во чисел: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Введите числа: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a;
    }
    if (a < 0)
    {
        cout << "Это число меньше 0" << endl;
    }
    if (a > 0)
    {
        total= a* a;
        sum += a;
    }
    cout << "Сумма квадратов: " << total << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, вы не поняли условие.

Я его понял так - вы вводите число N, ну, скажем, 12. И суммируете квадраты всех четных чисел, лежащих в диапазоне [1,N] - т.е. для 12 это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проще всего посчитать эту сумму так (нужно немного знания математики):

```
cout << "Введите число N: ";
cin >> n;
n /= 2;
cout << "Сумма квадратов: " << 2*n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/3 << endl;
```

Математика сводится к вычислению суммы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом вполне объяснимо условие, что если N меньше 0, то получается ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    cin >> a;
}
```

т.е. вы в цикле собрали N чисел, но ничего с ними не делали, а уже после цикла что-то сделали с `a` - вот вам и неверный результат :)

всю остальную логику тоже надо в цикл этот разместить

Answer (score 0):

Естественно у Вас будет выводиться только последнее число, ибо Вы перезаписываете каждый раз переменную "a". Оберните 2 if блока после цикла for в этот же цикл.